# Execute SQL Statement more than once like a For Loop

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL query (normal one). I have to run this query **4 times continuously** (like a For Loop in programming). How can I have something like an array and repeat the query execution?

SQL Server

**Update :**

I am updating some data based on a  column `TargetLocation`. This target location has values from 1 to 5. For each value I need to update the records that have same target location.

Comment: Why do you need to execute the same query more than once? There is looping in t-sql but it should generally be avoided in favor of a set based solution. If you can post details of what you are really trying to do we can help you find a solution that doesn't require a loop.

Comment: What is your desired result? Do you want one result set with every row quadrupled or do you want to return four result sets?

Comment: I am not expecting result sets , I am updating some data  based on one column

Comment: @JSantosh: Ah, OK. The term "SQL *query*" was misleading, since it is usually only used for SQL statements which return some kind of result.

Comment: Now that you have learned how loops work in t-sql you should forget they exist. They are awful for a number of reasons. Concurrency, performance and code maintenance are the main issues. Almost everything except for some administrative maintenance tasks can be done set based. It takes a change in how you think of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like a simple SQL WHILE loop?

```
declare @counter int
set @counter = 0

while @counter < 10
begin
select 'foo'
set @counter = @counter + 1
end
```

Comment: Thanks man. This worked. I don't know that `while` works in SQL . :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are running the query in SQL Server Management Studio, then you can use GO N to run a query N times.  For example:

```
insert into MyTable (MyCol) select 'NewRow'
go 4
```

This will insert 4 rows into MyTable with the text 'NewRow' in them.

If you really need to loop over something in another application, then I recommend using the while loop as suggested by Peter Tirrell.

Note that loops are usually unnecessary in SQL.  They may indicate code that is written with procedural logic instead of set-based logic.

Answer (score 2):

I **think** you want a join in your UPDATE, as in:

```
--create two sample tables that we can work on
declare @tabletoupdate table(ID int,TARGETLOCATION int);
declare @sourcetable table(ID int,SOURCELOCATION int);

--drop in sample data
insert into @tabletoupdate select 1,10 union select 2,20 union select 3, 30;
insert into @sourcetable select 1,100 union select 2,200 union select 3, 300;

--see the 'before'
select * from @tabletoupdate
select * from @sourcetable

--make target look like source
update @tabletoupdate
set
  targetlocation = s.sourcelocation
from
  @tabletoupdate t
  inner join @sourcetable s on s.id = t.id;

--show 'after'
select * from @tabletoupdate
select * from @sourcetable




/*
--if you really insist on doing it with a loop
--bad because its 
--1) slower
--2) less readable
--3) less reliable when other users are accessing the data
declare @currentID int = 0;
declare @maxID int = (select max(id) from @sourcetable);
while @currentID < @maxID
begin
  set @currentID = @currentID + 1;
  declare @newval int = (select sourcelocation
    from @sourcetable
    where id = @currentID
    );
  if @newval is not null
  begin
    update @tabletoupdate
    set TARGETLOCATION = @newval
    where id = @currentID;
  end
end
--*/
```